# Group (Wholesale) Pricing Not Displaying on Product Page

Tags: configurable-product, group, associate-products, pricing

I have Configurable products with Associated Products attached. It's essentially just dresses in different sizes, and colors. However, when I added "Group" pricing for our wholesale customers, it only displays the "wholesale" price on the main catalog view. When I click on the item, the regular retail price is displaying, and even when I add to cart, it's not using the "Wholesale" price. I am logged in as a wholesale customer. Does anyone know how to get the product page to display this wholesale/group pricing?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that I have to actually add the wholesale pricing to all the simple products as well. Once I did, it worked perfectly.

Comment: please share your experience so that I can configure the same.